# Can Asynchronous Window process use session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I am handling a piece of code (process an excel file) asynchronously by window thread.

Before processing the code I am setting a session variable and sending the response back to client.
When the callback method is called, can it change the session value?
Will I be able to access the Session value by AJAX call?
What happens to the session, Can the window thread access it?

Answer (score 1):

> Will I be able to access the Session value by AJAX call?

No of course not. Session lives only on the server. No client side javascript could access it. If you are talking about accessing the session in background threads from the server that might still be a problem because there's no longer a current HTTP request associated to the current thread. The best solution in this case would be to pass the value you need as a parameter to the thread (`state` object) instead of using ASP.NET session.

Comment: Suppose you have written a WebMethod and you are calling it from a javascript code using AJAX, in that case will this request handled by  any IIS worker process?
Will that WebMethod be able to get Session value?

Comment: Yes, in this case you will be able to access the session. If this WebMethod is an asmx web service you have to enable session but if it is a PageMethod you could access it from `HttpContext.Current.Session`. But once again I would not use Session at all. I will have the AJAX call pass the required information to the WebMethod. Or pass some identifier so that the WebMethod could use to retrieve the actual data from some data storage (such as a database or something).

Comment: Again I have one question in my mind.
To access a session value you need to know the session Id which is sent back to browser and stored in a cookie (for cookiefull session). So does AJAX call passes this cookie information to server side?

Comment: Yes, AJAX calls pass the session cookie.

Comment: It depends. In most cases not as there will no longer be an HTTP request available when this thread runs.